# Where do I execute my on-first-start functions in my Electron app?

Tags: node.js, electron

I am using Electron 9 and I have a main process and a single render process. On the first start of my application I would like to execute some code which is not executed on the second run.

Does Electron have a dedicated location where I should do this? Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: There is [this](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/app#apprequestsingleinstancelock) API, but I think the idea here is that only one instance can run at a time. You might have to write a counter to a file on start an decrement it on close to keep track of this. Also, are you interested in the first start of a set of applications running at once? Or the first start on the current Windows session, or what?

Comment: Thanks! I will look into this. I mean in general just the very first start of the app after installation so I can create some default preferences in the user directory

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Use `app.getPath('userData')` - it's dedicated location for your apps data for current user (eg. in windows it will point to  something like `AppData/Roaming/app-name/`)
2. At startup use:

```
app.on('ready', () => {
  const firstTimeFilePath = path.resolve(app.getPath('userData'), '.first-time-huh');
  let isFirstTime;
  try {
    fs.closeSync(fs.openSync(firstTimeFilePath, 'wx'));
    isFirstTime = true;
  } catch(e) {
    if (e.code === 'EEXIST') {
      isFirstTime = false;
    } else {
      // something gone wrong
      throw e;
    }
  }

  // ...
});
```

3. Profit!

https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_file_system_flags - why use `wx` flag
https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_opensync_path_flags_mode - `fs.openSync()`
https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/app#appgetpathname - `app.getPath()`

If you want to write out default preferences in the first run and read them in the next runs, try this:

```
import defaults from './default_preferences.json'; // will work for plain js objects too

let prefs = defaultPrefs;

app.on('ready', () => {
  const prefsPath = path.resolve(app.getPath('userData'), 'prefs.json');
  let isFirstTime;
  try {
    fs.writeFileSync(prefsPath, JSON.stringify(defaultPrefs), { flag: 'wx' });
    isFirstTime = true;
  } catch (e) {
    if (e.code === 'EEXIST') {
      // slight posibility of races, you can eleminate it by using `singleInstanceLock` or waiting loop for `write` flag
      prefs = require(prefsPath);
      isFirstTime = false;
    } else {
      // something gone wrong
      throw e;
    }
  }

  ...
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That's almost what I need, but one last question regarding the startup. This goes into my `main.ts`, but I would like to import a renderer module which has the init function (which creates a bunch of files). It's located in `./app/prefs`, but it doesn't let me do it because on startup it can't find `prefs` from the main process. Do you have a hint for that? Do I really need to separate that or can I use this module in `main.ts` as well?

Comment: Can you elaborate more? What is your file structure?

Comment: Main file is `./main.ts` and the file that creates these default files is located in `./src/app/core/prefs.ts`

Comment: Ahh, you want on first run create `prefs.json` in `userData` and in the next runs you want to import it?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I want to create a `prefs.json`, created by `prefs.ts` on first start

Comment: Yes, exactly thats it! Not only on the "next run", but first create the file and also load it in the same session with these default values. On the next start of the app I just want to load it (because it already exists)

Comment: I've added example